# swipe to refresh not working with list and grid on the same screen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

> i am using recycler view for list and grid on the same screen but swipe to refresh not working

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

> any suggestions where i am doing wrong or Am i  implementing in a wrong way?

Comment: Can you post a snapshot of the layout? I am not sure if SwipeToRefreshLayout can be used with multiple recyclerviews in them. A guide for implementing swipe to refresh : https://guides.codepath.com/android/Implementing-Pull-to-Refresh-Guide

Comment: i think you are right i used two swipe to refresh for both the recycler views and it's working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> this is what worked for me
>
> ```
> <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
>         android:id="@+id/list_refresh"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content">
> ```

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/trending_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/grid_refresh"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/trending_grid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

multiple recycler views do not work with same swipe to refresh

> as swipe to refresh can contain only one child

`